# Does a phrase "I'm gonna raise a whim flag on this one" make any sense?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests

Does the phrase “I’m gonna raise a whim flag on this one” make any sense?  Put simply, I want a phrase to have the same meaning as “I’m going to resign from further engagement in this matter”.

Comment: It certainly doesn’t make any sense to me. A whim is a spurious idea or impulse, or it’s a kind of [mining capstan thingy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whim_(mining)) used to raise things from mines. Neither of those options makes any kind of sense when put together with _flag_. The sentence is complete nonsense to me. Did you by any chance mean a ***white flag***? Raising the white flag is an idiom that kind of makes sense in your context, though it refers to surrendering more than just resigning from some matter.

Comment: What I had in mind was this meaning:
"a sudden desire or change of mind, especially one that is unusual or unexplained."
I wasn't aware of any other ones.

Comment: You can do something _on a whim_, meaning that you do it on a sudden, spur-of-the-moment impulse. I still don’t see how that can meaningfully combine with _flag_. (In my first comment, ignore the word _spurious_. I think I meant to type ‘sudden’ and somehow typed a completely different word.)

Comment: Admittedly, I wasn't at all familiar with the word.
Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please feel free to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site. 
You might also be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.

Comment: I now think this is a perfectly valid question, and that @keshlam has pointed us toward the answer; still, it would be nice to see more context, so that we may determine whether the hypothesis is true.

Comment: So, @bigpapa, is this a phrase you have written yourself, or have you come across it somewhere [where was that?]. If it's a phrase you have generated yourself, why did you choose *whim*? (If that's already in comments, then it needs to be in the question)

Comment: Yes, I wrote it myself. I'm fairly certain that the _white flag_ isn't what I wanted to communicate. As pointed out already, it's tantamount to surrendering whereas the context was as follows: 
_Up to this point, the dialogue focuses on a charity fundraiser_

A: So where do we wanna go to get it started?  

B: You know what, I think I'm gonna raise a _whim flag_ on this one. At least for now. Please, though, keep me in the loop.  

For a reason unknown, I very specifically desired to use the flag context. No need to pursue it any further: I already replaced it with a slim _withdraw_.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intended to use the idiom "raise a white flag", meaning surrender. With that change, the sentence says something close to what you intended.

(It may or may not mean that you concede the point under discussion. Surrendering one battle doesn't necessarily mean conceding that the war has been lost.)

Comment: Disagree. He asked if the phrase made any sense. I'm pointing out that with this minor correction it *does* make sense and in fact is exactly what he was trying to say.

Comment: I think keshlam has discovered the truth of the matter. What it looks like to me is that "raise a whim flag" is a case where *whim* is an OCR fumbling of *white*. We see a lot of that these days when print sources are transferred to digital media without adult supervision.

Comment: This policy discussion belongs on Meta, if anyone cares enough to pursue it. Feel free to delete this answer and write a better one.